# With node.js, how to manage npm across modules?

Tags: node.js

For example, I have following structure

```
main
    -- doTask1
        -- task1-1.js
        -- task1-2.js
    -- doTask2
        -- task2-1.js
        -- task2-2.js
```

If I run `npm install <some package>` in `doTask1`, a new directory `node_modules` is created in `doTask1`.

Now in `doTask2`, I need to use the same package, do I need to run `npm install <some package>` in `doTask2` again? It will create another `node_modules` in `doTask2` which is duplicate. What's the correct way to manage this?

Comment: You can install a module globally.

Comment: Don't do what Shomz is suggesting. I am pretty sure there's a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I knew I could install globally but I felt something wrong, so I asked to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NPM resolution of node modules that are not referenced with a relative path, is to first check current directory, and then traverse upwards each directory from current looking for a **node_modules** folder.

So in your situation, just install in **main** if you want the same version of the same package / module:

[image]

Finally, you could install the required package / module **globally** - however, this is usually only recommended for packages you know you need from the command line anywhere (for instance gulp, webpack etc). In your situation, for modules specific to the application it is best to keep them **locally** installed under a **node_modules** folder.

Some helpful NPM documentation on installing npm packages:

- See "Loading from node_modules Folders" [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#loading_from_node_modules_Folders)
- A slightly old but relevant blog post [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation in a nice format. It's good to know it will traverse upwards looking for the node_modules folder.

Comment: @JoeHuang - no probs, thanks for acknowledging the answer. Have added a link at the bottom of the answer to some helpful docs which goes into more details if interested.

Comment: Updated the docs link to a blog which actually better describes the process.